# Cannot start DataProc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to create DataProc cluster using the Google Developer console. Unfortunately, whenever I select the DataProc cluster menu I'm getting redirected to the Cloud Dataproc API page with a message

Dataproc API is not enabled on this project. Redirecting to Dataproc API management dashboard.

However I have this API already enabled, in fact, the page I'm redirected to has a green checkmark with Enabled text.

I've tried everything, from disabling and enabling API again to even creating new projects and trying there. Neither worked. Hence my question, did someone face such a situation? If so what is the solution?

Comment: This seems to be a UI problem. Have you tried gcloud https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create